# Can I hide a web seed in a torrent file?

Tags: bittorrent

I want to seed a torrent from direct link. But users can see a direct link in .torrent
file web option, so that they will not use the torrent and could go to directly download from
the link.

Any one have idea to hide web seed in torrent file option, so that no one can see direct
link, but they download data from that link using torrent download software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all users have the expertise to figure out that there is a direct link on your torrent that they can use in their browse or web manager. Maybe they "have the right" to use your web server. ;) Anyway, for must users it would be wiser to use torrent plus your direct link peer for the best download.

Anyway, I am trying to figure out what is your motivation to do this, I think you would get better advice if you explain this. I imagine it is bandwidth. What you could possibly do is to restrict the User-Agent in your web server so they can only work with certain clients, but others would be impacted or you could throttle your web server with certain parameters.

Comment: So your answer is you hope that they are ignorant?

Comment: Did you read it complete?? I said the first part as a joke. More "knowledge" more rights. :) Limiting by user agent could be a good choice, for example. Apple does that with their trailers website so only Quick Time can be used unless you spoof the user agent.

Comment: @HKReleaseGroups you are not listing the directory with the files, are you?

Comment: I have a 10mbps unlimited web server.I uploaded a torrent with web seeding from my webserver.Many users started downloading that file from my web server not using torrent.They downloaded that file from download accelerator.My web server shows too busy.So if have any idea to hide web seed in .torrent file. My previous two comment not completed by mistake.Please delete those comments.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is for something that will let the someone's torrent client hide the fact that it is getting a file (or part of one) from a direct link.

While there might be some client out there that will do that, you can not force people to use.

What you are then asking is in effect for people (or their computers) to both know and not know something at the same time.

This is impossible (unless you control all of the software that is being used).